# Is it possible: Forward Two iPhones to One Mac?

Tags: iphone, mac

I have two iPhones (work and personal) that I want to forward (messages, calls, etc.) to one Mac. The two phones use different Apple IDs, which may be make this not possible.

Is this possible? Can someone please show me how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same Apple ID in Messages Settings to forward messages from one device to another.